# Why can't I get the height between the nav bar and the top of the keyboard correctly?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a weird problem.  I'm trying to calculate the exact height between the bottom of the navigation bar and the top of the keyboard no matter which iOS device I'm running the app on.  Here is the method where I'm doing this calculation:

```
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
            let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
            let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height
            let viewableArea = screenSize.height - keyboardRectangle.height - reportPostInstructionContainerViewHeight - characterCountContainerViewHeight - reportPostInstructionContainerViewHeight + 4
            //iPhone 12 and above is "- 20"; iPhone 8 needs to be "+ 4"; iPhone 12 mini is "- 24"
                        
            print("**** navigationBarHeight: \(navigationBarHeight)")
            print("**** keyboardHeight: \(keyboardHeight)")
            print("**** screenSize.height: \(screenSize.height)")
            print("**** total screen height - keyboard height: \(screenSize.height - keyboardRectangle.height)")
            print("**** viewableArea: \(viewableArea)")
            textViewHeight = viewableArea
            print("**** textViewHeight: \(textViewHeight)")
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.01, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.textView.anchor(
                    top: self.horizontalDividerView.bottomAnchor,
                    leading: self.view.leadingAnchor,
                    bottom: nil,
                    trailing: self.view.trailingAnchor,
                    identifier: "ReportPostPFAVC.textView.directionalAnchors",
                    size: .init(width: 0, height: self.textViewHeight)
                )
                self.textView.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
```

The line where "viewableArea" is being calculated seems to be the issue.  For example, if I'm running the app on an iPhone 8, I need to add 4 to this calculation in order to size the text view properly.

Here is an image for reference:

[image: Screenshot showing that the bar with the "Report" button is correctly sitting on top of the keyboard]

I'm trying to get the bar with the "Report" button to sit perfectly on top of the keyboard.  But, if I test on different devices sometimes I need to subtract 20 or 24 instead of adding 4.

I don't really understand where this gap is coming from.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to approach this from a different angle as I am not sure where exactly your issue is and what exactly was your logic from the code alone that you provided.

What you need to achieve is to find the coordinates of two frames in the same coordinate system. The two frames being; the keyboard frame and the navigation bar frame. And the "same coordinate system" is best defined by one of your views such as the view of your view controller.

There are `convert` methods on `UIView` which are designed to convert frames to/from different coordinate systems such as views.

So in your case all you need to do is

```
let targetView = self.view!
let convertedNavigationBarFrame = targetView.convert(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds, from: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
let convertedKeyboardFrame = targetView.convert(keyboardFrame.cgRectValue, from: nil)
```

In this example I used `self.view` as my coordinate system in which I want the two frames. This means the coordinates will be within a view controller. To get a height between two frames (which is your question) I could use absolutely any view that is in same window hierarchy and I should be getting the same result.

Then in this example I convert bounds of navigation bar from navigation bar, to target view. I found this to be best approach when dealing with `UIView` frames.

Last I convert keyboard frame to target view. The keyboard frame has a screen coordinate system which leads to using `from: nil`.

Getting the vertical distance between them is then a simple subtraction of two vertical coordinates

```
convertedKeyboardFrame.minY - convertedNavigationBarFrame.maxY
```

To have a full example I cerated a new project. In storyboard:

- I added a navigation controller
- I set the navigation controller to be "initial".
- I set the old auto-generated view controller to be the root view controller of the navigation controller.
- I added a text field which will trigger the
  appearance of keyboard.
- Then applied the following code:

**The example code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    
    private lazy var checkView: UIView = {
        let checkView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        checkView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        checkView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        checkView.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.view.addSubview(checkView)
        return checkView
    }()
    
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            
            let targetView = self.view!
            let convertedNavigationBarFrame = targetView.convert(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds, from: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
            let convertedKeyboardFrame = targetView.convert(keyboardFrame.cgRectValue, from: nil)
            
            checkView.frame = CGRect(x: 30.0, y: convertedNavigationBarFrame.maxY, width: 100.0, height: convertedKeyboardFrame.minY - convertedNavigationBarFrame.maxY)
        }
    }
         
}
```

The `checkView` appears between navigation bar and keyboard to show that the computation is correct. The view should fill the space between the two items and border is used to show that this view does not stretch below keyboard or above navigation bar.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer!

What does this line mean?

checkView.frame = CGRect(x: 30.0, y: convertedNavigationBarFrame.maxY, width: 100.0, height: convertedKeyboardFrame.minY - convertedNavigationBarFrame.maxY)

I don't quite understand what the x coordinates are for?

Comment: @JFortYork I added an example view to show/demonstrate that the computed frames are correct. It is just a black view with red border that extends between the two views. The horizontal coordinates were just randomly picked as they are not relevant for example. You will not be using it but rather the height.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @JFortYork why do you even need the height between navigation bar and keyboard? From the code where you setup anchors it seems more like that you want it between `horizontalDividerView` and your keyboard frame. So simply replace (twice) this `self.navigationController!.navigationBar` with `horizontalDividerView`. Perhaps this is the issue now.

Comment: Let me give this a shot.

Comment: Strange...now your original method works. I think it's a simulator issue.

Comment: The bizarre thing is that it only works on various iPhones if I use this line:

let height: CGFloat = convertedKeyboardFrame.minY - convertedNavigationBarFrame.maxY - 175

Comment: @JFortYork It is hard to tell from your code what all effects this height and why this magic number 175 is present. Why don't you try and anchor your view to bottom of the screen instead of setting its height? The bottom offset could be `self.view.bounds.maxY-keyboardFrame.minY`.

Comment: Which view are you referring to?

Comment: Disregard, I found the problem.